# Using PhantomJS with Selenium Webdriver and Python

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs

I'm currently using Selenium Webdriver to do some validation on pages. The Webdriver is being driven by PhantomJS. I know that in PhantomJS, you can listen to the network using the example like the one below: (from https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Network-Monitoring).

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onResourceRequested = function (request) {
    console.log('Request ' + JSON.stringify(request, undefined, 4));
};
page.onResourceReceived = function (response) {
    console.log('Receive ' + JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 4));
};
page.open(url);
```

How can I achieve this functionality within the Webdriver? Can I bind a function to the DesiredCapabilities?

Comment: How is this a python question?

Comment: [Proposed solutions didn't work for me, but this one works (it uses driver.execute_script)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36427562/1334996)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve here? It is possible to inject javascript. So with that you could create a object that listens to the page and logs this into an object that you grab later on when you made some actions.

Ill give it a try but I'm not sure what phantomJS does.

```
browser.execute_script("    
var requests= [];
var received = [];
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onResourceRequested = function (request) {
    requests.push('Request ' + JSON.stringify(request, undefined, 4));
};
page.onResourceReceived = function (response) {
    received.push('Receive ' + JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 4));
};
page.open(url);");
```

Later (if your still on the same page) to get the requests:

```
browser.execute_script("function(){return requests }()");
```

and the received connections:

```
browser.execute_script("function(){return received}");
```