# Prevent CSS/other resource download in PhantomJS/Selenium driven by Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs, headless-browser

I'm trying to speed up Selenium/PhantomJS webscraper in Python by preventing download of CSS/other resources. All I need to download is img src and alt tags. I've found this code:

```
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, request) {
    if ((/http:\/\/.+?\.css/gi).test(requestData['url']) || requestData['Content-Type'] == 'text/css') {
        console.log('The url of the request is matching. Aborting: ' + requestData['url']);
        request.abort();
    }
};
```

via: [How can I control PhantomJS to skip download some kind of resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486377/how-can-i-control-phantomjs-to-skip-download-some-kind-of-resource)

*How/where can I implement this code in Selenium driven by Python? Or, is there another better way to stop CSS/other resources from downloading?*

Note: I've already found how to prevent image download by editing service_args variable via:

[How do I set a proxy for phantomjs/ghostdriver in python webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699718/how-do-i-set-a-proxy-for-phantomjs-ghostdriver-in-python-webdriver?lq=1)

and

[PhantomJS 1.8 with Selenium on python. How to block images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371495/phantomjs-1-8-with-selenium-on-python-how-to-block-images?lq=1)

But service_args can't help me with resources like CSS. Thanks!

Comment: If all you want is the HTML and select elements from the page, is Selenium/PhantomJS the best option? Have you considered using [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)?

Comment: @brechin, that's a great idea, thanks! Unfortunately I don't think python-requests can get javascript injected content. For example, see the main image on this page: https://www.everlane.com/collections/mens-luxury-tees/products/mens-v-antique. Everything in `<div id="content" class="clearfix">` is injected via backbone.js, and in my output from python-requests, I simply get an empty div with the `<!-- Filled in by Chaplin -->` comment...

Might I be missing something?

Comment: I'd look at the requests and just grab https://www.everlane.com/api/collections

Answer (score 7):

A bold young soul by the name of “watsonmw” [recently added](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/commit/d9b65ed014ed9ff8a5e852cc40e59a0fd66d0cf1) functionality to Ghostdriver (which Phantom.js uses to interface with Selenium) that allows access to [Phantom.js API calls which require a page object](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/), like the `onResourceRequested` one you cited.

For a solution at all costs, consider building from source (which developers note “takes roughly 30 minutes ... with 4 parallel compile jobs on a modern machine”) and integrating his patch, linked above.

Then this (untested) Python code should work as a proof of concept:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs')

# hack while the python interface lags
driver.command_executor._commands['executePhantomScript'] = ('POST', '/session/$sessionId/phantom/execute')

driver.execute('executePhantomScript', {'script': '''
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, request) {
    // ...
}
''', 'args': []})
```

Until then, you’ll just get a `Can't find variable: page` exception.

Good luck! There are a lot of great alternatives, like working in a Javascript environment, driving Gecko, proxies, etc.

Comment: It seems that the patch is already in Ghostdriver 1.1.0, but when I start it (with `phantomjs /path/to/ghostdriver/1.1.0/src/main.js`) and connect to it (with `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(port=8910)` ) I still get `Can't find variable: page`.

Answer (score 4):

Will's answer got me on track. (Thanks Will!)

Current PhantomJS (1.9.8) includes Ghostdriver 1.1.0 which already contains watsonmw's patch.

You need to download the latest PhantomJS, perform the following (`sudo` may be required):

```
ln -s path/to/bin/phantomjs  /usr/local/share/phantomjs
ln -s path/to/bin/phantomjs  /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
ln -s path/to/bin/phantomjs  /usr/bin/phantomjs
```

And then try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs')

# hack while the python interface lags
driver.command_executor._commands['executePhantomScript'] = ('POST', '/session/$sessionId/phantom/execute')

driver.execute('executePhantomScript', {'script': '''
    var page = this; // won't work otherwise
    page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, request) {
    // ...
}
''', 'args': []})
```

Answer (score 2):

Proposed solutions didn't work for me, but this one works (it uses **driver.execute_script**):

```
driver.command_executor._commands['executePhantomScript'] = ('POST', '/session/$sessionId/phantom/execute')

driver.execute_script('''
    this.onResourceRequested = function(request, net) {
        console.log('REQUEST ' + request.url);
    };
''')
```